# Why Fourier transform for linearized NS?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fourier-transform, navier-stokes, linearized-theory

I'm reading a paper and has the linearized NS equation and follows it by getting the solution through a Fourier transform. What is the thought behind this? Meaning, why use a Fourier transform?

$ \rho\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} = -\nabla \mathbf{p} + \eta \nabla^2 \mathbf{v}$

$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}=0 $

Comment: To turn a differential equation into an algebraic equation?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, partial differential equations have no universally-applicable solving method: If some solution is available by some method, and when the existance and uniqueness of the solution is established, then the recipe is accepted.

Therefore, there is many technique available to solve the partial differential equations. Among them, Fourier transform and Laplace transform are particularly useful, because, as @Qmechanic pointed out, it transforms the differential equation into algegraic equations, which is more easy to solve.

However, the transformation method has its limitations: Fourier transform method only can find the solutions  which is square-integrable, and Laplace transform can catch the solution only slower growing than exponential growth.